# Expose a directory on my server for download over HTTP

Tags: gratis, web-apps, ubuntu, http, sharing

I want to expose a directory on my Ubuntu server, for user to explore over a browser and download. Users would be within my LAN, and I don't have security/authentication need.

Any software which provides an interface like this would work - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.16/

Most important: 1. Ease of use, 2. Transfer speed, 3. Ease of installation

Answer (score 2):

The one of the fastest ways will be

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Useful links:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html
- http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/

If you can't access created website, check your's Linux user permissions.

Comment: Where should I put the files to be served?

Comment: In the directory, where you start the server, e.g., if you are in **/home/lukasz/test**, run **python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000**, then all files stored in this directory will be available.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that sprung into my mind is to install and run the default HTTP server:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

and then copy in `/var/www/html` the files and directories you want to share, or just change the DocumentRoot location.

The interface that will be shown to the users will be exactly like the one you linked.

You'll need to learn some basic Apache webserver configuration, but it's not that hard and it's a skill that might be useful to you in the future.

Comment: I tried apache2, and changed the DocumentRoot, restarted the server, then it started giving me "Forbidden" message. Do you have a sample configuration which works ?

Comment: Do a `chgrp -R www-data /foo/bar && chmod -R 775 /foo/bar` where `/foo/bar` is your DocumentRoot.

Comment: You'd need to change the access rules in the Apache configuration as well if you changed the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Check for all occurences of the "old location" and adjust them accordingly.